# Swift - How to remove delay when recording audio using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, audio, stream, avaudioplayer

I'm using an app that records audio and streams it to another user. It's basically a VoIP call. The problem I'm running into is that the audio I'm streaming to the peer is delayed by about 0.5 seconds. This is quite noticeable, and a little annoying when you both try to talk at the same time.

I'm wondering if this is common among AVFoundation's AVAudioEngine, or if possibly it's something to do with the way I set it up.

I can include source code if this is NOT a known problem with AVAudioEngine, otherwise can you please suggest the best route to record audio with the least delay?

I would also prefer something that is fairly high-level, and compatible with swift 3/3.1. However, if there is not a solution that meets these needs, then recommend the tool you think seems best fit.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you call "AVAudioEngine.inputNode.installTap" function with the minimum supported bufferSize of 100 ms or (sampleRate * 0.1) samples.

Comment: Thank you for your input. So I tried setting the buffer size to 100, however, it seems to default to 4410. This is my code:
        localInput?.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 100, format: localInputFormat) {  (buffer, when) -> Void in
But when I print out the buffer.frameCapacity and buffer.frameLength they are both 4410...

Comment: The bufferSize parameter - preferred size of audio buffer in samples(!). If the sampleRate is 44100, the minimum supported bufferSize will be 4410. Replace "100" by "4410".

Comment: By default I had the bufferSize at 4410. So unfortunately, this won't work.